# Why I can't get the content of a post?

Tags: wordpress

My code :

```
<div class="date"><?php the_time('d') ?> <?php the_time('M') ?></div>
<h2 class="titolo" style="min-height:0;"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>                                                                        
<div class="descrizione"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
```

time and title are correct. But the content is empty?

In fact, trying :

```
$pr=get_posts();
print_r($pr);
```

I see both title and description inside the array. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Not really! Or, I don't think so? :D

Comment: Heh, did you use also a while loop to extract contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="date"><?php the_time('d') ?> <?php the_time('M') ?></div>
<h2 class="titolo" style="min-height:0;"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>                                                                        
<div class="descrizione"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<div class="alert alert-warning"><h4>Warning</h4><p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yeah, now I get the_content(). But why before it didn't work? P.S. the last </div> is wrong, remove it

Comment: updated to remove div. you have to see if there are posts before you can display the content of a post.

Answer (score 0):

you can use $content = get_the_contnet(); or $content = $post->post_content;

then treat $content as a normal php variable.